# Does it matter if a question title is in first person or impersonal?

Tags: discussion

I recently gained access to the edit review queue and an enthusiastic member of the site is doing lots of cleaning up in my time zone, which is great.

Every now and then an edit consist of changing just the title from third person *How do I...?* to an impersonal *How to...*

My personal preference when searching for things leans towards the *How do I...?* approach so I am reluctant to approve the edit when that is the *only* change that is made.  (Most often there are lots of other improvements).

Is there a preference?  I couldn't find anything in the usual help files.  Does it matter?

How about the difference between "File not found in..." and "How to find a file..."

Surely the people who need this site will just copy their error message into Google and see what comes up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a preference, but I would reject those edit as trivial:

From the page about the [edit privileges](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do
>   so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just
>   change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

I wouldn't count those under grammar errors; from your description they just sound like writing style changes **which didn't substantially improve the post**.

Comment: Thought so, cheers.